# Consume web service from same web application

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I seem to have struck a complete blank and will most likely have a homer moment when someone points me in the right direction.

I have a WCF Web Service which is consumed happily across asp.net, windows phone, windows services, etc, etc.  I'm adding a page to the same application in which the service resides, basically a "test" page that the user can go to and it'll do a quick call to the service to see if the server is up.

Now normally, you'd just throw in a Service Reference and bobs your uncle, but for the life of me, I just can't seem to click what I'm supposed to do when I'm accessing the service from within the same application, do I still add a service reference or is there a quicker way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: If they server is down surely the user won't be able to view the webpage regardless of whether it is accessing the service or not?

Comment: I guess I should have rather said that it's a way to see if the SERVICE is up vs SERVER.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reference the web service by its name in the code and see if you'll be able to create new object from that web service and then consume in the code, instead of creating a reference.

Comment: While that is a way to execute the logic behind a service, this way does not access it as a service. So to test whether WCF interface is still up, this isn't the way. A service reference to the service would be.

Comment: @CodeCaster, so am I correct in saying, the best way to do it is to actually add a web reference back to itself?

Comment: Great, thanks, I figured it's going to be that but something just didn't sit right, mainly due to the fact that it was from inside the actual service app.